# Audio switching from line to headphone and back, also so crack on audio

Tags: sound

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 on dual-boot.
When I use Ubuntu directly, no problems at all.
The thing starts when I go to Windows and then go to Ubuntu...

The settings window visibly flicker, the output device quickly changes form line out to headphones (and I do not have one) and a crack in audio may be heard.

I also recorded a [video](https://youtu.be/OWaB2zY-uFY) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: To be clear you do not have headphones but the sound out switches to them? Where are you seeing this?

Comment: I do not have headphones. The sound settings looks like its changing from one to another. I recorded a video and attached to this question, so you can better understand the behavior.